# Adjust slider label position sliderInput R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `sliderInput` on a Shiny app:

[image: Picture of a shiny slider]

If it's on the same line as another element, the label on the draggable slider will overlap those elements. If the width of the slider is set to 100%, the label will go off the screen, as in the above screenshot.

How can I adjust the js/css of the slider so that the label of the draggable slider is right aligned when in the max position, and left aligned when in the min position, so that it doesn't overlap any other elements or is cut off by the edge of the screen?

Reproducible code below:

```
library(shiny)

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
           by = "day")



ui <- fluidPage(

    sliderInput(inputId = "sldr", label = "", 
                min = min(dates), max = max(dates), value = min(dates),
                width = "100%")
    
)


server <- function(input, output) {

   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
           by = "day")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      #my-slider .js-irs-0 .irs-single {
        text-align: right;
      }

      #my-slider .js-irs-0 .irs-single:before {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
      }

      #my-slider .js-irs-0 .irs-single:after {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
      }
    "))
  ),
  sliderInput(inputId = "my-slider", label = "", 
              min = min(dates), max = max(dates), value = min(dates),
              width = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This didn't do anything. The sliderInput is inside a uiOutput, if that matters.